# (1) Running a .py in cmd and (2) with variable in same line

Tags: python, python-2.7

**I figured out the zip code in same line out. It's sys.argv[1], I had other code I neglected to comment out when trying out [1] that gave me the error. All I need help with now is getting weather.py to run without having to call the whole file path.**

I will preface with I'm not very experienced with python and may get certain names wrong or think something might work that obviously doesn't, bear with me I tried to word this to make as much sense as possible.

So I need to run a program using the command line. The program is complete and 100% functioning when ran in PyDev. The program is called weather.py, and what needs to trigger it in cmd is

> python weather.py (5 digit zip)

I cannot get the program to run using just 'python weather.py' first off. I have added C:\python27 to PATH as well as C:\python27\python.exe (not sure if that does anything). Getting the .py to run via those two keywords doesn't seem to work with what I've tried. I also need to be able to add a zip code to the same line to trigger the program. I was told about

> zipcode = sys.argv[0]

to allow the zip code to be automatically initialized as a variable, but I get

> IndexError: list index out of range

when I run the program using

> python C:\python27\weather.py

I tried replacing 0 with 1 or 2 because I'm unfamiliar with .argv but neither of those worked either. Any help getting the program to run using just python weather.py OR getting the zip code input to function on the same line is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some of the code? consider doing a print of `zipcode` right after the `zipcode=sys.argv[0]` I'm suspecting that that line isn't the one giving you the error?

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` should _never_ give an IndexError since sys.argv[0] is always the filename. If you want additional arguments, you'll have to get them with sys.argv[1] (or any sys.argv[n] for n>=1, depending on the number of arguments). After that, make sure that you really call the script with the arg, so it looks like `python weather.py 12345` (probably you do this, just to be sure). And finally, **are you editing the right file**? Maybe you're just coding in the wrong file, so the error _can't_ disappear if you change something...

Comment: Solved it. See above. All that's left is running it with python weather.py 12345

Comment: Part of the program requirements is to call with the correct arg or be able to handle the errors when the arg is blank or not 5 digits, which both work.

Comment: how are you trying to run it from the command line? Are you in the same directory as your script? You shouldn't really have scripts in the C:\python27\ directory.

Comment: I have it in python27 for simplicity in testing, but the requirement is to run it by only calling python and the name of the script. So far I can only run it with the complete file path.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you `import sys` in your code.

```
import sys
zipCode = sys.argv[1]
```

and actually provide an argument

EDIT:

For clarity, if sys was not imported, you would get `NameError` and not an `IndexError`. Additionally, when passing args in from the command line, the indexing actually begins at 0 where `sys.argv[0]` is always the program name and the provided args begin at 1. So, in this case, the zip code would be at `sys.argv[1]`

EDIT2:

variable name to avoid using reserve words :)

Comment: I have imported sys.

Comment: A missing import would not result in an IndexError

Comment: @palsch I realized that when I read over my answer again a second ago lol.

Comment: But you have correctly spotted the zip argument is `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: Solved it. See above. All that's left is running it with python weather.py 12345